# I want show price after edit a product(admin panel->catalog->products->edit product) in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, attributes, price, magento2.3, product-grid

On [this1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiCrb.png) online shop, the price("pret") for all variation is same.
I want that when I edit (and save) a product, to display the price on grid with products in admin.
I think that I must take price from variations and, after save, to put  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D31iS.png) price in grid.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must run the indexer on save. You can configure this in the adminhtml under "System => Index Management"

Keep in mind that this will slow down your shop!

Comment: I run index:reindex after save, but does not work.. the price is still empty on admin products grid after save.